# How to make animation add item to shopping cart like Amazon iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm implementing feature add to cart in my e-commerce iOS app. And i see Amazon app has a good animation when increase from 9 to 10. But i don't know how to make the same that.

I have attached image with animation.

[image: Add item to cart Amazon iOS app]

I appreciate all your guidance.

Comment: Are you talking about the basket icon increasing and shrinking in size and changing the number 9 to 10?

Comment: @JoeBenton yeah, That is what I mean.

Comment: By coding it, by trying around, playing around, fiddling around - that is how most things get created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to use a custom view for the uibarbuttonitem in the navigation bar. This custom view then has a button:

```
UIButton *backBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIImage *backBtnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-back"];
[backBtn setBackgroundImage:backBtnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[backBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
backBtn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 33);
UIView *customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 63, 33)];
[customView addSubview:backBtn];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customView];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

You can then animate this custom uiview. In the action of the button you animate the frame bigger and then in its completion you animate in back to smaller size again.